# SharePoint Online: display extra information on the Right Display pane of the list calendar view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calendar, json-formatting

I have a SharePoint Online list with a calendar view and when you click the day cell, all information is shown on the right as shown on the image.

Currently it is displaying the Title (see right pane), but I would like to display another field below it. See second image below.

[image]

Show extra information under the title and set the background color of the item to match the one in cell.

So, two things:

1. show the value of another field below the title on the right pane
2. set the background color of the event on the right to match the in the cell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no settings/options available in SharePoint online lists to show additional fields in right side details pane/unscheduled pane.

Also, this is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting capabilities as well. SharePoint JSON calendar view formatting only supports adding extra CSS classes to the calendar/event item using `additionalEventClass` attribute.

**Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON Calendar view customizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-calendar-formatting)

**Related Read**:

1. [Create a modern Calendar view in SharePoint Online/Microsoft Lists](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/)
2. [Unscheduled Pane in Microsoft Lists Calendar Views](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/06/21/unscheduled-pane-in-microsoft-lists-calendar-views/)

---

If you want Microsoft to provide this new feature to allow showing additional fields in right side details pane/unscheduled pane, you can add a new feedback/idea on SharePoint feedback portal at: [SharePoint Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: How do I set the background of the event on the details pane to match the one in the day cell? I can set the vertical line to red, but I want to set the background to red as well. When selected I want to show a background dark red, for example.

Comment: I don't think currently there is any way to do it using JSON formatting.